# Route [events] not defined using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want when I type the address `http://localhost/agendab/public` or when I open my web application, it will redirect directly to `login`, or when I click on disconnect, it will redirect to `login`.

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::resource('events', 'EventController')->middleware('auth');
```

**loginController.php**

```
protected $redirectTo = '/events';
public function login(Request $request)
    {   
        $input = $request->all();
  
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
  
        $fieldType = filter_var($request->name, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'name';
        if(auth()->attempt(array($fieldType => $input['name'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
        {
            return redirect()->route('events');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('error','Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
        }
          
    }
```

**Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/events');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use Laravel resources, you need pre-defined way to call. Ex for the `index` you have to call `events.index`, if `update` then `events.update`...

> In case you're calling a custom route in the same `EventsController` the **defied it before the resource route**.

[image]

---

**In RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/events.index');
}
```

or

```
return Redirect::route('events.index'); #using facade
return redirect()->route('events.index'); #using helper class
```

---

FYK

1. [HTTP Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects)
2. [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)
3. [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Redirect proper route name

```
return redirect()->route('events.index'); // loginController.php
```